# Error getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I make an android program using Android Studio. When i run the program, there are error "02-16 14:59:31.715 17216-17249/com.anastasia.voicemap E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10".

This error appear when call the function to show map.

There are the fullest error what i got :

```
02-16 14:59:31.715 17216-17249/com.anastasia.voicemap E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10    
02-16 14:59:31.715 17216-17249/com.anastasia.voicemap E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled  
02-16 14:59:48.665 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
02-16 14:59:48.665 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.  
02-16 14:59:48.685 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)  
02-16 14:59:48.685 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.  
02-16 14:59:48.685 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the following Android Key exists:  
02-16 14:59:48.685 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API:    API Key: AlzaSyAG6cQ7UQ39oYzoXAMJEUIo3F--wKAsyB8  
02-16 14:59:48.685 17216-17408/com.anastasia.voicemap E/Google Maps Android API:    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): C0:8A:92:85:63:3B:90:F8:04:A5:F8:07:46:C1:31:78:F7:C9:2D:5B;com.anastasia.voicemap  
02-16 15:00:01.595 17216-17216/com.anastasia.voicemap E/WhetstoneSDK-JNI: on Load native Whetstone
```

Thanks in advance!
Agung

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the Google Maps Android API is enabled in your Developer's Console. If it is, check if you put the Android API Key in the `google_maps_api.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my network was unable to access google services.
Play store, Gmail and Google search was inaccessible, but there is internet connection.
Check your access to google services when this error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You must Have internet on, 
it should on when you install/start ur app, When you acess any service from server you must have internet.